# GCP Functions manipulating static XML file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We came with a need in our company where we have 1 big XML file (200mb+) where we need to modify it per user.
For example, user X will modify it's content via our web platform, which will send an API request to our Cloud Functions with what is needed to be modified -> our Cloud Function should then upload a modified XML file (based on the original 200mb+ file) to a bucket.

We have been trying to figure out how to attack this kind of functionality for serval days, we even considered separating the XML file into few and then combining it to one file based on user modifications.

All of the methods we came with requires us to first: download the xml file -> load it into parser -> make modification -> upload new file to user bucket
The mentioned process above takes too long as it involves in downloading the file and then uploading a new file, where we are trying to achieve the same just with loading the file locally via static files.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: as an idea - get rid of that XML file entirely. It is not a database to support integrity, concurrency and so on. Keep/maintain the data properly - i.e. CloudSQL or Firestore and generate that XML file on a request when needed.

Comment: This is another approach we are looking at, although querying that amount of data and then parsing & serving it as an XML file to the user in a manner of seconds is extremely tricky.
Firestore wouldn't work as the cost would be extremely high as each XML file will need to be separated into hundred of thousands documents within Firestore

Comment: Do you need to expose the 200Mb XML file to the users? Or only a subset? 200Mb is huge to transfert in HTTP!

Comment: Only a subset, also the XML will be comprised using GZIP before sending it

Comment: Given the volume of data you are dealing with and the type of operations you want to perform, a database feels like the only viable option. Besides, Firebase/Firestore allows up to 1GB of storage free...So unless you're making in excess of 50K reads and 20K writes per day it should be extremely cost effective.